# MVC Change dateformat in index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have an indexView with a column named Month with "day-m-y time", and i want to display it just the Month and year name. 
[Dateformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuIdG.png)
how can i do it? ive tried dataannotations but doesn not work..
[image]

```
    [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
            [Display(Name = "Select Month")]

            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Month { get; set; }
```

The view contains this :

```
 <th data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Month)">                
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Month)
            </th>
```

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor` will print the name of the property, ie `Month`, not its value. How do you render the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can format date in View  example as follows

```
<span>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.EffectiveDate).ToString("MMM-yyyy")</span>
```

For can also format date from model

```
[Display(Name = "For Period")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")]
```